# Rhc login fail during the setup

Tags: command-line-interface, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I've tried to setup my OpenShift account using CLI and RHC. I followed the steps here https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/osx.html#client-tools . When I try the "rhc setup", it asks me for login and password I enter my OpenShift account email and password (with those I easily login in the OpenShift website and also in the Web Console of my application) and it gives me "Username or password is not correct"!!
Anyone knows why this is happening??

Comment: Which OpenShift version are you using? The OpenShift 2 version which is what ``rhc`` is for has effectively been shutdown. The latest OpenShift 3 is very different and the command line client for it is ``oc``. What URL are you using for accessing the web console for OpenShift? Make sure you are using documentation for the correct version.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton that solved my problem! I was using OpenShift 3 (the only one you can sign in to now) and rhc, so it was impossible to work! I wasn't even thinking that rhc could had been shutdown. Maybe they should remove the getting-sterted guide if they are not supporting it anymore.